# Beautiful Soup Page Source Error

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to fetch the html source from this usl:
http://books.google.com/books?id=NZlV0M5Ije4C&dq=isbn:0470284889

I used the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib, urllib2, urlparse, argparse, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getPageSoup(address):
    request = urllib2.Request(address, None, {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'} )
    urlfile = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    page = urlfile.read()
    urlfile.close()
    print 'soup has been obtained!'
    return BeautifulSoup(page)

soup2 = getPageSoup(address)
metadata = soup2.findAll("metadata_row")#this content is present when viewing from the web browser
```

However, the html source from soup2 looks hardly like the source from the Google Books page:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html><head><title>Quantitative Trading: How to Build Your Own Algorithmic Trading Business - Ernie Chan - Google Books</title><script>(function(){function a(c){this.t={};this.tick=function(c,e,b){b=void 0!=b?b:(new Date).getTime();this.t[c]=[b,e]};this.tick("start",null,c)}var d=new a;window.jstiming={Timer:a,load:d};try{var f=null;window.chrome&amp;&amp;window.chrome.csi&amp;&amp;(f=Math.floor(window.chrome.csi().pageT));null==f&amp;&amp;window.gtbExternal&amp;&amp;(f=window.gtbExternal.pageT());null==f&amp;&amp;window.external&amp;&amp;(f=window.external.pageT);f&amp;&amp;(window.jstiming.pt=f)}catch(g){};})();
    </script><link href="/books/css/_9937a87cb2905e754d8d5e36995f224d/kl_about_this_book_kennedy_full_bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/></head></html>
```

HTML source from urllib2 and my web browser are very different. How can I get the correct page source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct page source. All visible content of page is generated by JavaScript. So, it's impossible to fetch actual content using urllib. You should use browser extension, webkit bindings or something like that.

Comment: thank you! that's pretty inconvenient, that one needs to install a full-fledged JS engine and QT bindings. But all the same, I guess there's no other way...